# how to play all formats of videos in dnn with html5 video tag?

Tags: dotnetnuke, html5-video

I'm using html5 video tag to play a video in dnn.Here .mov videos only playing in dnn,but i want to play .mp4, .flv, .mpeg etc.im normal aspx pages every video playing but in dnn only .mov .

```
<html5:Video ID="video1" runat="server" Url="~/Videofiles/trailer_480p.mov" Width="300" Height="300" DisplayControls="true" AutoPlay="true"></html5:Video>
```

This works fine in dnn,but if i want to play .mp4 it's not supporting.
And also i tried like this:

```
<video width="320px" height="240px" autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay"  controls="controls" poster="/video/thumb/vide1.jpg">    
<source src='Videofiles/VIDEO  India.mp4' type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
```

Any idea appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried making sure MP4 is enabled in IIS? By default I don't believe IIS will allow that mime type.

You'll need to add it in IIS
Extension: mp4
MIME type: video/mpeg

You can probably add it in the web.config if you are using IIS7 using code like the following.

```
<system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: in my iis i have default:extensions-.mpa,.mpe,.mpeg,.mpg,.mpv2 and MIME type-video/mpeg and Entry Type-local.Do i need to add anything more?

Comment: You would need to add MP4 if you want those available